# How to generate an index based on geographical features of a given address?

Tags: gis, analysis, geographic-distance

I am trying to find an efficient way to generate, based on a provided geographical location, an index that is made up of various geographical features.

For example, given an address `Address 1`, the code will look at that given address and calculate:

1. `supermarkets` = Number of supermarkets in a radius of 1 km
2. `rivers` = Number of rivers in a radius of 2 km
3. `gyms` = Number of gyms in a radius of 3 km

Based on this, an index `index` = `supermarkets` + `rivers` + `gyms`

From my research, there are a few pieces of software that can be used to process geographical data, such as ArcGis or perhaps by using Google Maps API. I am however not sure what would be the best for this kind of purpose that would be easy to implement, or how difficult this problem even is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use a traditional RDBMS and that you would prefer to avoid, if possible to leverage geospatial components but just use SQL.

If these assumptions are valid, have a look at this: https://www.drdobbs.com/database/space-filling-curves-in-geospatial-appli/184410998

EDIT: Apparently you would like to use R(or Python).
The original answer was language-agnostic and described a method to organize your data so that a query like you described could be easily modelled using only >= and <= as a selection criteria.

If you want to use GIS, here are relevant resources for R and Python.
R: https://mgimond.github.io/MEGUG2016/Tutorial.html
Python: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson1-Intro-Python-GIS.html

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have no experience with SQL or RDBMS and am more familiar with Python, R, Matlab. Do you have any recommendation that uses one of these approaches, or perhaps a more simple approach?

Comment: Your original problem was:
"generate, based on a provided geographical location, an index that is made up of various geographical features."

I do not think this is an appropriate approach. Because if you somehow encode "is < 2 km from an Hotel" as part of the index, the moment you remove that specific hotel, or add a new one, you will have to recalculate this index from scratch.

(continues below)

Comment: The most appropriate way would be to encode all your locations (including hotels and gyms) according to the schema suggested in the first article and then you can query your system about things like:

How many/which gyms are located inside a 2km radius from this point?
List all points that are no more than 3km from at least a gym and a hotel.

Note also that a "river" is not a point, so you will have to somehow handle these cases too by choosing an appropriate representation of rivers (or roads, or tracks) so that it fits the rest of your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From a naive perspective, it seems that location encoding is not a trivial task. I found some online databases of the geographical information I may need (https://livingatlas-dcdev.opendata.arcgis.com/maps/esrinl-content::openstreetmap-eten-drinken-/explore). Do you think that the Python or R scripts could be used to compute this kind of index based on the data from a database like this one?

Comment: I cannot help with that because GIS is outside of my skillset.
What I wanted to stress from the start, though, is that it does not make sense to "capture" spatial relationships in an index (assuming you are using this term in the DB sense), because this a difficult task, but especially because it will severely limit its usefulness.
Encode the "coordinates" as a property of each location, then use appropriate functions to find out distance among locations, or answer "is this inside this area or not?" questions.